# Conditionally dealing with exceptions during initialization of member variables

Tags: c++, exception

Hello good folk of StackOverflow.

Is there a better way of dealing with exceptions in the constructor of member variables? I am having to interact with a library class that may or may not throw an exception in it's constructor (cannot be checked ahead of time) and I want to avoid the use of pointers in my class (if there is a crash, I want all destructors to be properly called even if I mess up). I have currently settled on this implementation (included a dummy stub for an example):

```
class class_I_have_no_control_over{
  public:
    class_I_have_no_control_over( int someArgument )
    {
        if( someInternalConditionThatCantBeTestedExternally )
            throw anException;
    }

    class_I_have_no_control_over( )
    { //Does not throw
    }
}

class MyClass{
  private:
    class_I_have_no_control_over memberVariable;

  public:
    MyClass()
    {
        try{
            class_I_have_no_control_over tempVariable( 24 );
            memberVariable = std::move( tempVariable );
        }catch(...)
        {
            class_I_have_no_control_over tempVariable( );
            memberVariable = std::move( tempVariable );
        }
    }
}
```

The first method I considered is try catch initializer list : i.e.

```
class MyClass{
  private:
    OtherClassThatTrowsOnConstruct member;

    MyClass()
      try:
        member()
      {//Normal constructor
      }
      catch(...)
      {//Can translate an exception but cant stop it.
      }
```

But that method can only be used to translate exceptions, not stop them (if you don't throw an exception, the run-time will re-throw the original exception).

Some would say to use dynamic allocation (i.e. pointers with new and delete keywords) but as this library handles shared memory between processes, I am a little weary of what would happen to the dynamic memory contents in the event of a crash in one of the applications (ex. destructor never called and another application is waiting for the one that is no longer running never realizing that it is no longer listening).

Comment: The move operation indicates that the `class_I_have_no_control_over` uses dynamic memory allocation. What then prevents you from doing the same. Anyway, you could always use in-place construction (placement new), with a suitably aligned buffer.

Comment: What actually makes you sure that `class_I_have_no_control_over tempVariable( );` inside the `catch` will always succeed?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The comment in that constructor saying "Does not throw".

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well, fair enough ;) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version can be simplified somewhat, without changing its behaviour:

```
MyClass() try {
    memberVariable = class_I_have_no_control_over(24);  // move from temporary
} catch (...) {
    // no need to do anything; memberVariable is already default-constructed

    // Unless the class is so evil that move-assignment might fail and leave
    // the target in a messed-up state. In which case you probably want
    memberVariable = class_I_have_no_control_over();
    // If that fails, you should probably give up and let the exception go.
}
```

Unless you have further constraints (such as the class not being movable), this is the best way to deal with your situation. If it were unmovable, then dynamic allocation is probably a reasonable option; use a smart pointer, probably `std::unique_ptr`, to make sure it's destroyed along with the `MyClass` object.

```
#include <memory>

class MyClass{
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<unmovable_evil> memberVariable;

  public:
    MyClass() try {
        memberVariable.reset(new unmovable_evil(24));
    } catch(...) {
        memberVariable.reset(new unmovable_evil);
    }
};
```

You might also consider `boost::optional` as a not-quite-standard alternative to dynamic allocation.

Comment: re the "no need to do anything" comment, no, the, the member variable can be thoroughly messed up if the 24-construction succeeds but the assignment fails. the OP's code also fails to consider the messed up possibility, but in an more direct/obvious way. the smart pointer solution seems okay. re boost::optional, a simple way to do the same without a boost dependency is to use a std::vector, and emplace_back for the construction attempt.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes, I did forget the possiblity of move-assignment not providing a strong exception guarantee; but that won't be an issue unless it's doing something very odd.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: A vector doesn't offer any advantages over a `unique_ptr`; the object is still dynamically allocated.

Comment: oh yes, you're right re vector, i forgot that it can't use small buffer optimization. i'm just too enhusiastic sometimes. :)